# Sqoop import from a query in mysql using string filters in where

Tags: mysql, import, hdfs, bigdata, sqoop

I'm trying to perform this query in sqoop but seems like I'm not able to apply a right text filter in a string field. Here is my code:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxx --username xxxxxx --password xxxx \
--query 'select year(order_date) as year,department_name,sum(revenue_per_day) from revenue where department_name="Apparel" and $CONDITIONS group by year(order_date),department_name' \
--split-by department_name --target-dir /user/ --fields-terminated-by '|' -m 2 \
```

The message says:  Generating splits for a textual index column allowed only in case of "-Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true" the property passed as a parameter

So what should be the right split, in this case, to perform this query if the other two columns are aggregation?

Could some of you guys check what's wrong in my code? I have not found how to figure it out.

Comment: What the error you are getting ?

Comment: @SandeepSingh look first at all I got a message saying that I need --split-by so I added --split-by department_name and now I got :   Unknown column 'Apparel' in 'where clause' because it's not able to understand the where as string :(

Comment: `--split-by` - integer column should applied with it

Comment: @SandeepSingh the thing is that if you check my query i have two aggregate columns and 1 string so how should I apply the --split-by based in my code?